# How do I add up all the outputs of user inputs in a method?

Tags: java, methods, console, local-variables

I'm working on this program for CS class and want a user to enter in an amount for each coin, show them the money value of said amount of coins and then add up the money from each output.

What I have so far allows someone to enter in an amount of money for each type of coin and display how much money that many coins is, but I can't seem to figure out how to add all of the money values up at the end.  I need a separate method that will call up the amounts for all the money returned from each method.  Any help would be appreciated!  Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Coins {
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    quarterDollarAmount( );
    dimeDollarAmount( );
    nickelDollarAmount( );
    pennyDollarAmount( );
  }

  public static void quarterDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters: ");
    int quarterAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = quarterAmount * 0.25;
    System.out.println(quarterAmount + " quarter are $" + amount);
  }

  public static void dimeDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes: ");
    int dimeAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = dimeAmount * 0.1;
    System.out.println(dimeAmount + " dimes are $" + amount);
  }

  public static void nickelDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels: ");
    int nickelAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = nickelAmount * 0.05;
    System.out.println(nickelAmount + " nickels are $" + amount);
  }

  public static void pennyDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies: ");
    int pennyAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = pennyAmount * 0.01;
    System.out.println(pennyAmount + " pennies are $" + amount);
  }
}
```

Okay, so I changed all the methods to look like this with their respective coin type:

```
 public static double pennyDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies: ");
    int pennyAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = pennyAmount * 0.01;
    System.out.println(pennyAmount + " pennies are $" + amount);
    return amount;
  }
```

And added the method:

```
public static double totalDollarAmount( ) {
    double quarters = quarterDollarAmount();
    double dimes = dimeDollarAmount();
    double nickels = nickelDollarAmount();
    double pennies = pennyDollarAmount();
    int total = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
    System.out.println("Total amount is $" + total);
  }
}
```

But now, the Compiler Output says (I've taken out my system details for obvious reasons):

```
1 error found:
File: /Users//Documents/Semester 2/CS/Coins.java  [line: 51]
Error: /Users//Documents/Semester 2/CS/Coins.java:51: possible loss of precision
found   : double
required: int
```

And puts the cursor in between right before the + in + pennies;.  Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return amount;` and change the return type from `void` to `double` for all of your money related functions.

```
public static double quarterDollarAmount( ) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters: ");
    int quarterAmount = CONSOLE.nextInt( );
    double amount = quarterAmount * 0.25;
    System.out.println(quarterAmount + " quarter are $" + amount);
    return amount;
}
```

Then capture the returned value in a variable when you call the functions.

```
double quarters = quarterDollarAmount();
...
double pennies = pennyDollarAmount();
```

Then you can add the values stored in those variables together and do what you want with the result.

```
double total = quarters + ... + pennies;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `global` variable and set the result of calculation to this `variable` and add all the variable.

or

Change the return type of the function from `void` to `double` and do the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class variable

`public static double totalAmount=0.0`

which will be updated in each method with the code

`totalAmount += amount;`.

Then

```
    public static void getTotalAmount() {
       System.out.println(" Total Amount of coins are $" + totalAmount);
    }
```

will do the job.